# Building Block-Join-Parent Query Criteria with Spring-Data-Solr

Tags: java, spring, solr, spring-data, spring-data-solr

I have a Solr Core with Parent-Child Documents and I want to build dynamic Querys to search those documents.

I'm using `Spring-Data-solr` and want to use the Criteria-Class to build such queries for searching specific child documents and receiving the full parent + children I use Block-Join-Parent Query.

Working query example:

```
q   {!parent which=object_type:shipping_order}invoicenumber:31920000
fl  *,[child parentFilter=object_type:shipping_order]
```

I tried different things to concat this criteria-objects to build such a query but I don't find a good way.

Here is an try to build such a query in `Spring-Data-Solr`, but it does not work.

```
Criteria invoiceNumberCritera= new Criteria("invoicenumber").is("31920000");
        Criteria doctypeCriteria = new Criteria("doctype").is("Invoice");

        SimpleQuery query = new SimpleQuery("{!parent which=object_type:shipping_order}");
        query.addCriteria(invoiceNumberCritera);
        query.addCriteria(doctypeCriteria);
        query.addProjectionOnField(new SimpleField("*"));
        query.addProjectionOnField(new SimpleField("[child parentFilter=object_type:shipping_order]"));
```

StackTrace:

```
Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr: org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse ' AND invoiceNumber:31920000 AND doctype:Invoice': Encountered " <AND> "AND "" at line 1, column 1.
Was expecting one of:
    <NOT> ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...
    <BAREOPER> ...
    "(" ...
    "*" ...
    <QUOTED> ...
    <TERM> ...
    <PREFIXTERM> ...
    <WILDTERM> ...
    <REGEXPTERM> ...
    "[" ...
    "{" ...
    <LPARAMS> ...
    "filter(" ...
    <NUMBER> ...
    <TERM> ...

    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:649) ~[solr-solrj-8.1.1.jar:8.1.1 fcbe46c28cef11bc058779afba09521de1b19bef - ab - 2019-05-22 15:20:04]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:255) ~[solr-solrj-8.1.1.jar:8.1.1 fcbe46c28cef11bc058779afba09521de1b19bef - ab - 2019-05-22 15:20:04]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:244) ~[solr-solrj-8.1.1.jar:8.1.1 fcbe46c28cef11bc058779afba09521de1b19bef - ab - 2019-05-22 15:20:04]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:207) ~[solr-solrj-8.1.1.jar:8.1.1 fcbe46c28cef11bc058779afba09521de1b19bef - ab - 2019-05-22 15:20:04]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.query(SolrClient.java:1019) ~[solr-solrj-8.1.1.jar:8.1.1 fcbe46c28cef11bc058779afba09521de1b19bef - ab - 2019-05-22 15:20:04]
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.lambda$executeSolrQuery$9(SolrTemplate.java:519) ~[spring-data-solr-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.execute(SolrTemplate.java:167) ~[spring-data-solr-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 68 common frames omitted
```

Is there a good way to use Block-Join-Parent Query's in Spring-Data-Solr?
Like a Criteria-object where i can add other Criterias like

```
Criteria fieldCriteria = Criteria.where("invoiceNumber").is("300230");
blockJoinCritera.addCriteria(fieldCriteria);
```

Comment: Can you resolve this problem?